# How do I make this iterative (loop)?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

First: please do not tell me how to do this in jQuery or some other library. I have not been able to get them to work in the sharepoint environment I'm operating in answers need to be in vanilla javascript.

I used the following code to make a content feed into a div and I know that because it uses numbers to distinguish each individual there has to be a more elegant way to do this without repeating code.

```
<h3>Meet the Team</h3>
<ul>
<li><a onmouseover="mouseOver(1)" onmouseout="mouseOut()" href="#">emp1</a></li>
<li><a onmouseover="mouseOver(2)" onmouseout="mouseOut()" href="#">emp2</a></li>
<li><a onmouseover="mouseOver(3)" onmouseout="mouseOut()" href="#">emp3</a></li>
<li><a onmouseover="mouseOver(4)" onmouseout="mouseOut()" href="#">emp4</a></li>
<li><a onmouseover="mouseOver(5)" onmouseout="mouseOut()" href="#">emp5</a></li>
</ul>
</br>
<div id="contactInfo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseOver(x) 
 {
    if(x==1)
    {
        document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '<iframe height=\'300px\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\' marginwidth=\'0\' marginheight=\'0\' src=\"../Style Library/htmlContent/emp1.htm\" ></iframe>'; 
    }
    else if(x==2)
    {
        document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '<iframe height=\'300px\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\' marginwidth=\'0\' marginheight=\'0\' src=\"../Style Library/htmlContent/emp2.html\" ></iframe>';    
    }
    else if(x==3)
    {
        document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '<iframe height=\'300px\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\' marginwidth=\'0\' marginheight=\'0\' src=\"../Style Library/htmlContent/emp3.html\" ></iframe>';    
    }
    else if(x==4)
    {
        document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '<iframe height=\'300px\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\' marginwidth=\'0\' marginheight=\'0\' src=\"../Style Library/htmlContent/emp4.html\" ></iframe>';    
    }
    else if(x==5)
    {
        document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '<iframe height=\'300px\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\' marginwidth=\'0\' marginheight=\'0\' src=\"../Style Library/htmlContent/emp5.html\" ></iframe>';
        }
 }
function mouseOut() 
 {
    document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = '';
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this instead, since the only thing that is changing is the `emp` file name which you can build it on the fly.

```
function mouseOver(x) {
  if (x >= 1 && x <= 5) {
    var fileName = 'emp' + x + '.html';

    document.getElementById('contactInfo').innerHTML = "<iframe height='300px' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' src='../Style Library/htmlContent/" + fileName + "'></iframe>"; 

  }
}
```

A cleaner approach for the same use case, is to separate the concerns, i.e, let the `HTML` only have the layout of your page or view and use `Javascript` to bind the events instead of having them inline. This will help your code to be maintainable in the long run. And for the index that you want to pass in, you can use `data-*` attributes to hold them on each element.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Meet the Team</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a class="emp" data-index="1" href="#">emp1</a></li>
  <li><a class="emp" data-index="2" href="#">emp2</a></li>
  <li><a class="emp" data-index="3" href="#">emp3</a></li>
  <li><a class="emp" data-index="4" href="#">emp4</a></li>
  <li><a class="emp" data-index="5" href="#">emp5</a></li>
</ul>
</br>

<iframe id="content-iframe" height='300px' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' src=''>
  < /iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".emp");
var iframe = document.querySelector('#content-iframe');

//  hide the iframe on page load
iframe.display = 'none';

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var fileName = 'emp' + this.getAttribute('data-index') + '.html'; // or this.innerHTML.trim() + '.html';
    var src = '../StyleLibrary/htmlContent/' + fileName;

    iframe.display = 'block';
  });
});

elem.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  iframe.src = '';
  iframe.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: An even more cleaner solution would be to add the `<iframe>` in the DOM and just hide/show it and change its `src` instead of recreating and removing it on every mouseover/-out :)

Comment: @Sushanth, should/could I change "var elems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li a");" to "var elems = document.getElementByClass(".emp"); just in case I have other un-ordered lists of links?

Comment: @black_reaver As long as you have the `class` on the elements you could use `document.getElementByClass("emp");` or `document.querySelectorAll(".emp");` Double check the `.`

Comment: Check the edited code. Also included the suggestions from @Andreas

Comment: @Sushanth Excellent! But if we have the iframe in the DOM can't we get rid of referencing the "contactInfo" div?

Comment: @black_reaver Right. You can get rid of it. But you will still have to hide the `iframe` on `mouseout`. Check the edited post

Comment: This also allows me to move the iframe formatting to a CSS file and further separate the various components.

Comment: @black_reaver That should be your next step :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about javascript but maybe you can use something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < mouseOver.length; i++) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Now that I see this, a basic variable would work. Thank you for the reminder.